# Setup elasticsearch mappings in cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I try to setup my elasticsearch document by using https://github.com/cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch but I'm unable to setup `fielddata = true` for some of my fields - ([Elasticsearch doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html#_enabling_fielddata_on_literal_text_literal_fields)).

I've tried it this way:

```
$elasticSearch = ClientBuilder::create()->build();
$elasticSearch->index([
    'body' => [
        'testField' => 'abc'
    ],
    "mappings" => [
        '_doc' => [
            "properties" => [
                'testField' => [
                    "type" => "text",
                    "fielddata" => true
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'id' => 'my_id',
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by using the `putMapping()` method. This methods allows me to define my mappings.

```
//put mapping
$elasticSearch->indices()->putMapping([
    'index' => 'book',
    'type' => 'books',
    'body' => [
        "properties" => [
            'name' => [
                "type" => "text",
                "fielddata" => true
            ],
            'author_name' => [
                "type" => "text",
                "fielddata" => true
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```